# Store Custom UIView and it's CALayer to NSArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview, nsarray, calayer

I have custom UIView where there's lot of sublayers, I want to store UIView in NSArray and reload it to screen later. Is there anyway I could do that? Please help... Thanks!

Update:
I have UIView, that UIView has a root CALayer with lots of sublayers, what I want to do is to store that UIView along with it's CALayer's sublayers, so that when I want to access that UIView I'd still be able to see the same (just exactly how I stored/saved it).

Comment: Can you please explain more?

Comment: done :) sorry if I made you confused.

Comment: Not sure about "reload"? Just using a pointer to handle it. I don't understand what is the problem here? Maybe you need a singleton.

Comment: what do you mean a pointer?

Comment: the problem is I don't know how to store the UIView along with it's layer XD

Comment: sorry I'm a beginner :(

Comment: For example: you have a `UIView * view`, and add CALayer `[[view layer] addSublayer:calayer];` right. Then just store `view`, the `calayer` won't lose. Can you post some code have you tried?

Comment: I have code like this [archive addObject:canvas] where archive is an NSMutableArray and canvas is a custom UIView, but when I tried NSLog and count archive, it's empty. 0_0

Comment: Can you post the code you have?